# Strange ArgumentOutOfRangeException in for-loop

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I just encountered a strange problem in a simple for loop. I get an *ArgumentOutOfRangeException* when I try to access *input_list[i]*. *input_list* is a list of some objects and has two members. But *i* equals *2* when the exception is thrown.

```
var count = input_list.Count;
var taskList = new Thread[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    taskList[i] = new Thread(() => SomeFunction(input_list[i]);
    taskList[i].Start();
}
```

In the second version, I only introduced a local variable *k* that is used as an index for the *input_list*:

```
var count = input_list.Count;
var taskList = new Thread[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int k = i;
    taskList[i] = new Thread(() => SomeFunction(input_list[k]);
    taskList[i].Start();
}
```

This second version doesn't throw an exception.

So, how can *i* be *2* in this example? And why doesn't *k* become *2* in the same way?

I'm using version 4.6 of the .NET Framework and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Probably, thread(`taskList[i]`) starts, then the thread that started it continue the for loop and increase the value of `i`, then thread looks for `input_list[i]`, but i just increased and is `==` to `count`, so you have `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Also, have a read of this: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx

Comment: Thanks, that really answers my question. I wasn't aware of this problem with closures.